# How to login and then run command in linux ftp client?

Tags: bash, ftp

I want to be able to connect to a ftp server automatically using a single file. This input file contains commands to run in ftp session.
I am able to connect and login to a ftp server via terminal using:

```
ftp <IP>
  Connected to <IP>.
  220 ProFTPD Server (ProFTPD) [<IP>]
  Name (<IP>:current_user): USER
  331 Password required for USER
  Password:
```

I enter password, the output is:

```
230 User USER logged in
Remote system type is UNIX.
Using binary mode to transfer files.
ftp> ls
200 PORT command successful
150 Opening BINARY mode data connection for file list
drwxr-xr-x   4 USER  psacln       4096 Aug 11  2020 backups
drwxr-xr-x   2 USER  psacln       4096 Mar  2  2019 error_docs
drwxr-xr-x  53 USER  psacln       4096 Jul 10 03:18 httpdocs
drwx------   2 USER  root         4096 Aug  4 06:32 logs
drwxrwxr-x  12 USER  psacln       4096 Aug 10  2020 moodledata
226 Transfer complete
ftp>
```

Suppose a single file named **cmd** includes the command "ls" and also username & password:

```
#!/bin/bash
HOST=<IP>
USER=USER
PASSWORD=<PASS>

ftp $HOST <<EOF
user $USER $PASSWORD
```

Using above file as input to:

```
ftp <ip> < cmd
```

How to use this file to auto connect to this ftp server?

Comment: You did not specify, which platform you are using. If your ftp honours `.netrc`, have a look [here](http://www.mavetju.org/unix/netrc.php).

Comment: @user1934428 My platform is linux

Answer (score 0):

I've just solved it.
I just use encoded password in the bach script:

```
#!/bin/bash
HOST=<ip>
USER=USER
PASSWORD=$(echo <encoded password> | base64 --decode)

ftp -inv $HOST <<EOF
user $USER $PASSWORD
ls

bye
EOF
```

My password contains char &ampersand&, so it has error in connecting to ftp server.
Note that **<encoded password>** is obtained by:

```
echo '<PASS>' | base64
```

Just this!

Comment: Of course everyone with read permission to your script can trivially find out the password, but I guess that you have set your permissions to 0700?

Comment: @user1934428 Yes you are correct. thanks Muslim